# how to change particular values in string array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[] arraylist = {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
```

but now I want to replace  inside the array above to 1, to make it like this

```
String[] arraylist = {"0","0","0","1","0","0","0"};
```

Comment: can you explai in brief??
not understand what you want to do.

Comment: `arrayList[3] = "1";` What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: arraylist[position_no] = "newValue";

Comment: Please learn Java first before diving into Android. You'll spend far more time on SO otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once try follow if you know position you want to change

```
arraylist[3]="1";
```

Hope this will helps you.